# Firebase auth for social sign in in django rest framework

Tags: django, firebase, django-rest-framework

We are developing react native app with django rest framework as backend.We want social sign in using firebase auth.
But in that case how will I authenticate    tokens in django rest framework?

For normal email sign in we are using jwt authentication.

Now I am not getting how will I use JWT authentication for users who signed up through our app and firebase authentication for users who signed in using social sign in like google,FB and apple in django rest framework?

Answer (score 0):

I have used `django-allauth` module with REST API and token authentication. so as per my experience when user signup using social platform you just need to write custom `CustomLoginView` which will overwrite existing method `SocialLoginView`.

After calling post method you can customize your code and generate token using `JWT-Token` and pass that token to user. for example please find below code

```
class CustomLoginView(SocialLoginView):
    """
    To Customize social login response
    """
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
        user = self.user
        # check what you get in response from parent class post method.
        data['user']['token'] = # Write your logic to get Token for user
        return Response(data['user'])
```

So once user will have `JWT-tokens` They can use it while using application.
Refer https://dj-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for more details.